# Introduction to philosophy of science and metaphysics

Tags: reference-request

I am interested in some texts for a beginner in the ***philosophy of science*** and in the arena of ***metaphysics***. I am a physicist. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you maybe tell us what you're looking for, specifically? Are you interested in the history of these disciplines, or in the current status? What made these topics interesting for you? As it currently stands, every book about metaphysics would be a valid suggestion, which makes a bad question.

Comment: Well in that sense. I am a beginner in metaphysics. I would like to have some basic reads that can be built up further.

Answer (score 4):

Two good introductory texts in Philosophy of Science are:

- Samir Okasha's *Philosophy of Science: A Very Short Introduction* ([worldcat link](http://www.worldcat.org/title/philosophy-of-science-a-very-short-introduction/oclc/48932644)). Like the other texts in the Oxford UP VSI series, it's a very quick read, so while it doesn't cover the full range of compelling topics in the field, it introduces and motivates some that have been central. And Okasha is a talented player in the field, not just an observer.
- Ian Hacking's *Representing and Intervening: Introductory Topics in the Philosophy of Natural Science* ([worldcat link](http://www.worldcat.org/title/representing-and-intervening-introductory-topics-in-the-philosophy-of-natural-science/oclc/9371160)) is a bit older, longer, and richer, and also a very good starting point. It emphasizes experimentalism slightly more than other late 20th century texts did. While it does not cover the last 30 years, it anticipates some of what has happened, and is a good primer.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations. I like the idea of a short introduction. I will let you know how they were once I get hold of them :)

Answer (score 1):

Martin Curd's "Philosophy of Science; the Central Issues" (more of an anthology) and Merrilee Salmon's "Introduction to the Philosophy of Science" (a textbook) are the two texts they recommend first years at LSE.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get hold of the Introduction to the Philosophy of Science. Going to read it now :)

Comment: No problem, I hope it's useful

Comment: I like this :) it's a really good book. But it's slightly slow moving for me haha.

Answer (score 1):

"Realism and the Aim of Science" by Karl Popper has explanations about both metaphysics and philosophy of science. See also "The Fabric of Reality" and "The Beginning of Infinity" by David Deutsch, which both discuss philosophy of science and metaphysics.

Comment: Wow these sound interesting. Thank you so much :) Will find these ASAP.